# ksh - How insert a echo command in a variable

Tags: variables, insert, ksh

how can i insert this command line in a variable? :

```
echo "abc:def" | awk -F':' '{print "field1: "$1 "\nfield2: "$2}'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) also applies to ksh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval`:

```
eval `echo "abc:def" | awk -F':' '{print "export field1="$1 "\nexport field2="$2}'`
```

Comment: you mean myvar=eval `echo "abc:def" | awk -F':' '{print "export field1="$1 "\nexport field2="$2}'`  ?

Comment: No, simply the line above.  It'll set the env variables `field1` & `field2`.  That is what you intended, right?

Comment: Not exacly.. i want create a variable with that code. For example `listnames="name1 name2 name3" echo $listnames`. I want create a variable because then i create a file in wich i'll write the content of var like this for example : `listnamesfile=home/_names.dat
touch $listnamesfile
echo $listnames  >> $listnamesfile`... but with this particular command line i can't. I can't write `myvar=echo "abc:def" | awk -F':' '{print "field1: "$1 "\nfield2: "$2}' echo $myvar` . Understand now?

Comment: Use backticks.  ``myvar=`echo "abc:def" | awk -F':' '{print "field1: "$1 "\nfield2: "$2}'` `` & `echo "${myvar}"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
testVar=`echo "abc:def" | awk -F':' '{print "field1: "$1 "\nfield2: "$2}'`
echo $testVar
```